# Adding Bootstrap to Site.Master

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I need to add bootstrap in site.master page. I did this in order to achieve this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" path="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" />

                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
```

Is this enough or do I need to add reference to bootstrap.min.js too and if I do where should I add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest keeping js and CSS files in 2 different folders. Then import the bootstrap css files in the header and the bootstrap js files in the body as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrapCSSFilename1.css") %>' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrapCSSFilename2.css") %>' />
</head>
<body>
    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootStrapFileName1.js") %>'></script>
    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootStrapFileName2.js") %>'></script>
</body>
```

replace the filename1, 2, etc.. as per the js files you have in bootstrap package.
Following is a sample folder screenshot with the bootstrap files.

[image: Usual bootstrap css files]

[image: bootstrap js files]